# changing the url name when posting jquery html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wondering to make my own changing of name for link just like here in Stackoverflow.I have not done anything for now because i dont have idea on how to do it. I am refering to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910803/changing-the-url-name-when-posting-jquery-html)

`Question`

When you post a link just like the link in `this` how do you do it?Instead of putting the entire `url` you just post the word `this` and when you click it, it still goes to that `url`

`Additional Information`

[image]

`Goal`

In my project I am posting Events every now and then. Sometimes i need to post link/url i want to make it fancy by posting link but making it like the one with stackoverflow `(check image)`. The way i post the event is also like stackoverflow asking question. How can i post a link and change it like the one in stackoverflow when you want to post a link you click the chain then put the link then write the title you want to appear it the question.

`Update`
I like to add something like when you press `CTRL + L` if you are in question or in answer

Comment: Have absolutely no idea what you are asking. If you want to change something in your code, show the code and expected results

Comment: When you post a link just like the link in `this` how do you do it..instead of putting the entire url you just post the word `this` and when you click it, it still goes to that url

Comment: Even with the picture it is still not at all clear what you are trying to do. Give a proper detailed description ... step by step if you have to

Comment: I think I can clarify - I think what he is trying to say is like in Gmail when you want to paste a link, you can have a textual representation instead of the actual link spelling. For example,  he wants to be able to create a link that says "Click Here!", and it will actually be a DOM element with `<a href="http://google.com/somethinghere">Click Here!</a>`, instead of a link that plainly says http://google.com/somethinghere.

Comment: @Hybrid yes like that you got what i mean

Answer (score 0):

So I took a few minutes to see if I can pull it off, and here is what I got:

https://jsfiddle.net/saxgtmjo/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="replaceableDiv">
You won't see this content!
</div>

<br>
Link Name: <input id="linkName" type="text" placeholder="Enter link title here!" />
<br>
<br>
Link URL: <input id="linkURL" type="text" placeholder="Enter URL here!" />
<br>
<br>
<button id="changeLink">Change link!</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#changeLink').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $link_name = $('#linkName').val();
    $link_url = $('#linkURL').val();
    $('#replaceableDiv').html("<a href='" + $link_url + "' target='_blank'>" + $link_name  + "</a>");
})
```

Your question is worded a bit oddly, so I do not know if you want to use some sort of POST information to populate the link name/url. If that is the case, then all you really need to do is use the JQuery code I provided in the `success:` attribute of the JQuery `$.ajax` or `$.get` or `$.post` function, and change the `$link_name` and `$link_url` according to the data retrieved.

Comment: yes i want it like this but i want it like the one with stackoverflow when i am typing like now i can insert a link like https://jsfiddle.net/saxgtmjo/1/ but the changed name should appear instead of the link of fidde.

Comment: yes i want it like this but i want it like the one with stackoverflow when i am typing like now i can insert a link like **this** but the changed name should appear instead of the link of fidde. `this should appear instead of the first comment see the difference in the link and the word ` `**this**`